# PHP e mysqli .Como aplicar um filtro sem acessar diretamente a super global $_POST

Tags: php

Como aplicar um filtro sem acessar diretamente a super global $_POST.
trocando isso:

```
$F['email']  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['email']);
```

Por isso:

```
$email = filter_input_array(FILTER_INPUT,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
$F['email']  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);
```

mas não funciona , qual a sintaxe certa se existe ??

Comment: Já tentou desta forma `$email = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, ['email' => FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL]);`

Comment: Porque você não quer acessar a super global? E no lugar dos filtros, na minha opinião vale mais a pena você criar sua própria expressão regular pra detectar e-mails e, se for o caso, sanitizá-los.

Comment: sim expressão regular  eu uso ,mas nesse caso é pra pegar dados que vem do formulário.com mysqli, dessa forma que escrevi eu uso com o pdo , mas para o mysqli não funciona entende.

Answer (score 0):

Assim também da certo:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'email',FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```